# Gatling not sending metrics to InfluxDB using graphite protocol

Tags: grafana, influxdb, gatling, graphite, scala-gatling

I followed the BlazeMeter article to monitor Gatling tests with Grafana and InfluxDB but no data is sent to InfluxDB and not any database created with the name "gatlingdb". InfluxDB is up and listen to port :2003. This is the log from InfluxDB:

```html
2022-01-07T13:57:53.019217Z info    Starting graphite service   {"log_id": "0YuD8znW000", "service": "graphite", "addr": ":2003", "batch_size": 5000, "batch_timeout": "1s"}
```

And I set gatling.conf fields to these:

```html
data {
    writers = [console,file,graphite]      # The list of DataWriters to which Gatling write simulation data (currently supported : console, file, graphite)
    console {
      light = false                # When set to true, displays a light version without detailed request stats
      writePeriod = 5              # Write interval, in seconds
    }
    file {
      bufferSize = 8192            # FileDataWriter's internal data buffer size, in bytes
    }
    leak {
      noActivityTimeout = 30  # Period, in seconds, for which Gatling may have no activity before considering a leak may be happening
    }
    graphite {
      light = false              # only send the all* stats
      host = "localhost"         # The host where the Carbon server is located
      port = 2003                # The port to which the Carbon server listens to (2003 is default for plaintext, 2004 is default for pickle)
      protocol = "tcp"           # The protocol used to send data to Carbon (currently supported : "tcp", "udp")
      rootPathPrefix = "gatling" # The common prefix of all metrics sent to Graphite
      bufferSize = 8192          # Internal data buffer size, in bytes
      writePeriod = 1            # Write period, in seconds
    }
```

and influxdb.conf contains below parameters

```html
[[graphite]]
  # Determines whether the graphite endpoint is enabled.
  enabled = true
  database = "gatlingdb"
  # retention-policy = ""
  bind-address = ":2003"
  protocol = "tcp"
  consistency-level = "one"

  # These next lines control how batching works. You should have this enabled
  # otherwise you could get dropped metrics or poor performance. Batching
  # will buffer points in memory if you have many coming in.

  # Flush if this many points get buffered
   batch-size = 5000

  # number of batches that may be pending in memory
  # batch-pending = 10

  # Flush at least this often even if we haven't hit buffer limit
  # batch-timeout = "1s"

  # UDP Read buffer size, 0 means OS default. UDP listener will fail if set above OS max.
  # udp-read-buffer = 0

  ### This string joins multiple matching 'measurement' values providing more control over the final measurement name.
   separator = "."

  ### Default tags that will be added to all metrics.  These can be overridden at the template level
  ### or by tags extracted from metric
  # tags = ["region=us-east", "zone=1c"]

  ### Each template line requires a template pattern.  It can have an optional
  ### filter before the template and separated by spaces.  It can also have optional extra
  ### tags following the template.  Multiple tags should be separated by commas and no spaces
  ### similar to the line protocol format.  There can be only one default template.
  templates = [
       "gatling.*.*.*.count measurement.simulation.request.status.field",
       "gatling.*.*.*.min measurement.simulation.request.status.field",
       "gatling.*.*.*.max measurement.simulation.request.status.field",
      "gatling.*.*.*.percentiles95 measurement.simulation.request.status.field",
      "gatling.*.*.*.percentiles99 measurement.simulation.request.status.field"      
  ]
```

Now I am running test through gatling but after successful completion of test no database with name galingdb is getting created on influxdb.

I am not sure what else I need to add.

Answer (score 0):

You need create database manually:

```
> influx
> CREATE DATABASE gatlingdb
```

Comment: Ideally I dont need to create database explicitly if events will reach influxdb properly .For now I created database but after completion of run still its showing blank database.

Comment: Alas, but the database needs to be created manually, or you can write a script that will create it once.
Ok, let's return to your problem. 

How do you run Influx? Do you properly pass the path to the config (with graphite and etc.)?

Comment: I start influxdb with command "/usr/local/opt/influxdb@1/bin/influxd -config /usr/local/etc/influxdb.conf"  and influx with command "/usr/local/opt/influxdb@1/bin/influx".I am running everything on localhost on mac.Also influx after starts shows "Connected to http://localhost:8086 version 1.8.9"